# How to set datetime property of blazor component in Markup?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

If I have a Blazor Component with a datetime property,  How do I set it through the markup? I just get an error cannot convert 'int' to 'datetime?'.

```
public class MyComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public DateTime? Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value == value) return;
    
            _value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
        }
    }
}
```

In razor page:

```
<MyComponent Value="2022/01/01"></MyComponent>
```

Is there way to somehow create an implicit conversion for the property?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the date parameter as a string then you have to change the `Value` property type to `string?` and parse it to `DateTime?` in the setter. (I don't know why someone would want to do that.)

**MyComponent.razor:**

```
@code {
    private DateTime? _value;

    [Parameter]
    public string? Value
    {
        get => _value?.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        set
        {
            if (value == null) _value = null;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out var result))
            {
                if (_value == result) return;

                _value = result;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<MyComponent Value="@("2022/01/01")"></MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<MyComponent Value="new DateTime(2022/01/01)"></MyComponent>
```

or

```
<MyComponent Value="dateField"></MyComponent>

@code
{
    private DateTime? dateField = new DateTime(2022/01/01);
}
```

or to bind the value, so when it changes the field changes too:

```
<MyComponent @bind-Value="dateField"></MyComponent>
```

Comment: Oh thanks,  I guess I was expecting something more complex that would let me specify the value as an actual string like "yyyy/mm/dd" without the c# code around it

Comment: I've updated my anwser with @bind-Value, is better to use, becaus when it changes the value of the field changes too.